# JSF not working on WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: java, jsf-2, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am Using the WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile in Eclipse Juno.
I configured my AppServer (server.xml) and added the jsp-2.2, jsf2.0, localConnector-1.0 and servlet-3.0 Feature.

When I deploy my project and open a JSP-Page in my browser, all went fine.
But when I want to open a JSF-Page, then I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR   ] An error occured while initializing MyFaces: org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.DefaultFacesConfigurationMergerFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.myfaces.spi.FacesConfigurationMergerFactory
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[ERROR   ] SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1353)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:862)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:753)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:5694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:444)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:249)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:550)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:899)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:172)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:320)
... 22 more
```

My web.xml was generated by eclipse and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>WAS-Liberty-Test</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>
        State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>

    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>

    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>

    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you may have both enabled the jsf-2.0 feature, but also bundled your own copy of MyFaces inside of your application.

If you wish to use the jsf-2.0 implementation shipped as part of Liberty I would suggest removing the MyFaces jars from your application, and also removing the StartupServletContextListener which should not be required in an integrated environment.

If you instead wish to use the jsf implementation bundled in your application, you can remove the jsf-2.0 feature from your server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jsf/myfaces lib from your application and Change the server configuration. Go to Feature manager and add jsf 2.0/jsf2.2.